# JNLP file: not to create desktop shortcut

Tags: java, desktop, shortcut, jnlp, java-web-start

In our webstart JNLP file, I have removed the shortcut and desktop tag, but when installing the webstart app, it still prompts me if I want to create a desktop shortcut.

So in the information tag it looks like this:

```
<information>
    <title>Dynamic Tree Demo</title>
    <vendor>Dynamic Team</vendor>
    <icon href="sometree-icon.jpg"/>
</information>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to add query params to the `href`  e.g. if the current value is `the.jnlp`, make it `the.jnlp?a=b`.  The JWS client will presume it is generated dynamically and will generally not create a desktop shortcut.

I say 'generally' since it is really up to the JWS client & how it is configured.

Comment: thanks. i tried this but it's still creating the shortcut. however i believe this is leading me to the right direction. i'll keep this updated if i can solve this later.

Comment: do you know where the Java WS is placing the Desktop shortcut?
where does it get the path to the desktop?

it seems somewhere in the registry but can't find it in documentation

Comment: @Horaasje *"do you know where the Java WS is placing the Desktop shortcut?"* It's putting it in whatever directory represents the desktop. *"where does it get the path to the desktop?"* Don't know, don't care. Why do you care?

Comment: Because I installed Java Application under a normal user.
I can't create shortcut on Desktop, while an superuser can create shortcut and it's placing it under another user's Desktop location.
So I want to know where Java Web Start, JNLP, is getting the path.
Somewhere in registry?
I've already checked ShellFolders and UserShellFolders and they are all correct.

Comment: @Horaasje You should ask a separate question. This is not something that can, or should, be taken up in comments.